# How to read a certain range of lines using systems calls

Tags: c++, c, system-calls

I am up a wall on an assignment that I have been hacking at for several days. Basically I need to make an executable program using C/C++ to take 3 queries from the user m,n and a file name.

The program will then output the text on those lines to the terminal. I must use read(), write(), open() and close() system calls to do it.

My approach is to go char by char (slow I know but everything else I tried seems to give segementation faults).

But it doesn't seem to work properly. When I use smaller parameters it just prints the whole thing, but if I use bigger parameters it doesn't print anything at all.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
// Task 2 of Lab 3

#include<unistd.h> // required library for the system calls
#include<fcntl.h> // required for system calls usage
#include <stdlib.h> // required for the use of exit statement, and atoi
#include<stdio.h> // required for the use of perror
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  int m = atoi(argv[1]);
  int n = atoi(argv[2]); // taking commmand line args by conversion with atoi
  int file; // integer value for holding the file descriptor
  ssize_t display;
  char *buff[1];
  int currentLine = 0;
  // open the first file for reading
  file = open(argv[3],O_RDONLY);
  if(file == -1 ){ // error handler for system call 1: open()
    perror("Did not open, exiting...");
    exit (1);
  }

  while(((display = read(file,buff,1)) > 0)){
    if(*buff[0] == '\n'){
      currentLine++;
    }

    if((currentLine >= m) && (currentLine <= n)){
      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff,display) != display){ // if statement doubles as error handling for read()
        perror("Problem with writing..."); // errror handling for write()
        exit(-1);
        }
      }

      else{

      }
}

  file = close(file); // Final system call close()
  return 0;

}
```

Sample testfile:

```
I have some information in here. 
Each line should print to the screen
3 lines total
make that 4
Wait? WHAT! I need 12 minimum???
Hm....
Wellp better start typing then. Let's see what can I write about?
Midterms are coming
They scare me
I hate exams, but I love code
woah i also need numbers in here uh 23
19 and lets do 100 and 400 just to add a couple more
maybe i should go ahead and add a 903 here
300
and that previous 300 got it's own line 
with this file ...

I have a good mix of chars,numbers, and symbols
that's good enough
time to test!
```

Comment: `char *buff[1]` that is dereferencing an uninitalised (garbage) pointer - `buff[1]` is out of bounds as `0` is the only valid index and you never init any pointer values anyway. If you want to read one character (highly discouraged) then declare as `char buff` and read using `&buff`.

Comment: Right, you pass the value of `buff` to `read`, but you never assigned it any value. So you're telling `read` to write the data to some random, uninitialized location. You allocate a pointer, but you never make it point to anything.

Comment: @kaylum you are a GOD! my code now works officially as intended changing `*buff` to `buff` and then replacing it in my system calls with &buff. buff[1] is unitialized because it's size is 1 so it goes out of scope in a sense right. God I'm such a noob :-(

Comment: So uh... Anybody want to post an actual answer so I can close this? It feels kind of wrong if I answer my own question.